# How was Sally Field's Oscar acceptance speech like dialogue from "Norma Rae"?

Tags: dialogue, academy-awards, norma-rae, places-in-the-heart

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sally_Field#1977.E2.80.9389):

> Then came a second Oscar for her starring role in the 1984 drama Places in the Heart. Field's gushing acceptance speech is well remembered and has since been both admired as earnest and parodied as excessive. She said, "I haven't had an orthodox career, and I've wanted more than anything to have your respect. The first time I didn't feel it, but this time I feel it—and I can't deny the fact that you like me, right now, you like me!"  Field was actually making a humorous reference to dialog from her role in Norma Rae, but many people missed the connection.

I've never seen [Norma Rae](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0079638/), so I was wondering if anyone knew what dialogue in *Norma Rae* might be involved.  I'm looking for a quote of the original dialogue from *Norma Rae*.

I tried searching the Oscar quote and Norma Rae, but no one else seems to be making this assertion online.  Apparently Burt Reynolds said that it was a humorous reference to *Norma Rae* in [But Enough About Me](https://books.google.com/books?id=HNgiDQAAQBAJ&lpg=PA190&ots=x5rJ0VB3Wv&dq=Norma%20Rae%20The%20first%20time%20I%20didn't%20feel%20it%2C%20but%20this%20time%20I%20feel%20it%E2%80%94and%20I%20can't%20deny%20the%20fact%20that%20you%20like%20me%2C%20right%20now%2C%20you%20like%20me!&pg=PA190#v=onepage&q=Norma%20Rae%20The%20first%20time%20I%20didn't%20feel%20it,%20but%20this%20time%20I%20feel%20it%E2%80%94and%20I%20can't%20deny%20the%20fact%20that%20you%20like%20me,%20right%20now,%20you%20like%20me!&f=false), but he doesn't include the *Norma Rae* line.

Note:  her speech was almost immediately parodied as "You like me; you really like me!"  So you may remember that quote better.  I suspect that her actual words are more closely related to the *Norma Rae* dialogue, "The first time I didn't feel it, but this time I feel it—and I can't deny the fact that you like me, right now, you like me!"

Comment: Your mission, should you choose to accept it, is to fix the internet. Anything and everything should be available via search.

Comment: Gotta love that the actual source on wikipedia after that claim actually doesn't say anything about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only quote / passage that makes any sense here is between Norma Rae and Rueben. There is a [**transcript**](http://www.script-o-rama.com/movie_scripts/n/norma-rae-script-transcript-sally.html) but it's poorly formatted.

A more formatted quote can be found on [**IMDB**](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0079638/quotes)

> Reuben Warshowsky: Under the circumstances, best wishes hardly seem enough. Thanks are in order. Thank you for your companionship, for your stamina, your horse sense, and a hundred and one laughs. I also enjoyed looking at your shining hair and your shining face.
>
> Norma Rae Webster: **Reuben, I think you like me.**
>
> Reuben Warshowsky: I do.
>
> Norma Rae Webster: I was gonna get you a tie clip or some shaving lotion, but I didn't know what you'd like.
>
> Reuben Warshowsky: Norma, what I've had from you has been sumptuous.